# Nginx upstream failure configuration file

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to start up my node service on my nginx webserver but I keep getting this error when I try to do nginx -t

```
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My current nginx.conf is like this:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:5555;
}

map $sent_http_content_type $charset {
    ~^text/ utf-8;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 100M; # Change this to the max file size you want to allow

    charset $charset;
    charset_types *;

    # Uncomment if you are running behind CloudFlare.
    # This requires NGINX compiled from source with:
    #   --with-http_realip_module
    #include /path/to/real-ip-from-cf;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        root /path/to/your/uploads/folder;
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I tried to look up some solutions but nothing seem to work for my situation.

Edit: Yes, I did edit the paths and placeholders properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tldr; The `upstream` directive must be embedded inside an `http` block.

---

nginx configuration files usually have `events` and `http` blocks at the top-most level, and then `server`, `upstream`, and other directives nested inside `http`. Something like this:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    upstream foo {
        server localhost:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        ...
    }
}
```

Sometimes, instead of nesting the `server` block explicitly, the configuration is spread across multiple files and the `include` directive is used to "merge" them all together:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Your config doesn't show us an enclosing `http` block, so you are most likely running `nginx -t` against a partial config. You should either a) add those enclosing blocks to your config, or b) rename this file and issue an `include` for it within your main `nginx.conf` to pull everything together.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me understand it better.

Comment:  glad to help!